# Change view in code swift

Tags: ios, swift, authentication, view

i have this Swift project where i have a tab bar Controller Scene, and i would like to add a view controller scene to act as a "Login scene", when the user is loged i want to switch the view to the tab bar controller scene.

I have implemented facebook login, so i have a method that is called when the login is completed. 
I have done this:

```
func loginDone(){
    let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("dashboardScreen") as! UITabBarController
    self.presentViewController(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

But that code brings me this error:

```
Attempt to present <UITabBarController: 0x7f87a37e8550> on <Project.LoginViewController: 0x7f87a352fca0> whose view is not in the window hierarchy!
```

What should i do?

Thanks!

Comment: Where are you calling this method from? You should not call it from init, viewDidLoad methods and others that are called before view is shown.

Comment: I was calling it from viewdidload, now i see the error. Where should i call it?

Comment: Call it from viewDidAppear for example.

Comment: why dont you try to handle this case in AppDelegate ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call it in `viewDidAppear()`, that way you can be sure that the login view is part of the app's view hierarchy.

You need to make sure the presenting view controller is in the app's view hierarchy. See the section 'Responding to View Events' in the [UIViewController Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/viewDidAppear:)

If you need more information on working with view controller's you can look at the [View Controller Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/)

Answer (score 0):

You should not call loginDone from init, viewDidLoad methods and others that are called before view is shown. Call it from viewDidAppear.